# Collapsed/Aggregated Data for XGBoost Classification/Probability Prediction

Tags: python, r, data-science, xgboost

I'm working on a project with the goal of predicting probability of a binary outcome for billions of observations. Given the number of observations and the fact that many of them will share the same set of covariates/features, we have collapsed the data set. Rather than the typical data set with one row per observation:

```
Obs. ID  Outcome    Covariate1  Covariate2
1        0          RED         FAST
2        1          RED         FAST
3        0          BLUE        SLOW
4        1          BLUE        SLOW
```

We have it aggregated to:

```
Covariate1  Covariate2  N   Outcomes
RED         FAST        2   1
BLUE        SLOW        2   1
```

There are four observations total, 2 have the RED/FAST combination, 2 have the BLUE/SLOW combination, 1 in each of those combinations experienced the event.

Ultimately, I want to predict the probability of experiencing the event given the covariates. What's the best way to achieve this without dis-aggregating to have one observation per row? In R using a GLM, I can provide collapsed data like this with successes and failures and it understands. I'm not sure how to replicate in XGBoost. Perhaps...

a) Using the `binary:logistic` objective with the collapsed data set, if XGBoost supports this natively (I have not found documentation supporting this yet).

b) Giving each collapsed block of observations 2 rows, one representing 'successes' and one representing 'failures', with an 'N' field that can be passed to the weight parameter and therefore giving more weight in the loss function to blocks with more observations using again `binary:logistic` as the objective?

c) Using the `count:poisson` objective with the number of successes as the outcome and the number of total observations as an offset?

d) A custom objective?

What do you think is the right solution? I'm fine implementing in Python or R if it matters.

Comment: Have you made any progress with this approach @jared-stufft?

Comment: @jared_mamrot unfortunately not. I read in a github issue somewhere that with the `reg:logistic` objective you can pass in the sample rate as the response but didn't have much luck getting any results from trying that.